# node js error in render (template show)

Tags: node.js, express

when i trying to create template and node execute that gives this error please help me

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "default" in views directory "C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\views"
   at EventEmitter.app.render (C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:519:17)
   at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:904:7)
   at C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\app.js:7:6
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
   at next (C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:13)
   at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:81:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
   at C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:235:24
   at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:313:12)
   at C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:229:12
```

Answer (score 0):

You are either in the wrong folder or you have no view named "default".

Comment: no my path is :- "C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\views\package.json" but give error still nw

Comment: Wait. Your path is what? You're running app.js from inside the views folder? Why is there a package.json file in your views? You should cd up one level and then run from there. Doing it from inside views makes no sense and would not work

Comment: i cant show u screen short but my file name is "default.ejs"

Comment: C:\Users\Act027\Desktop\node\views\default.ejs

Comment: Yeah, no I get that, but if your app.js is also in your views, your app isn't going to run. That would explain your error. You need app.js to one level up in your folder structure. You can't run it from views like that. Your package.json definitely has no business being in your views folder either!